# Multithresholding- OTSU method

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm trying to segment a specific part in a gray-scale image and I want to achieve this by applying the OSTU algorithm, but after using this function:

```
im = imread('ready.jpg');
oim =otsu(im,10);
figure,imshow(oim, [1 10]);
```

I could show the output image, but I do not know how can I save the result to be able to use it later as a mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry that I cannot see where your problem is. What do you mean by "how can I save the result?" If you want to use $oim$ in matlab, then it is already there. If you are interested in extracting one specific class, you can simply get the corresponding $n$th mask by calling $mask=(oim==n)$, which returns a binary mask with only the pixel belonging to the $n$th class marked as 1s.

If you are going to save the classification result outside of matlab, for example a tif image, simply use **imwrite** function in matlab. Late you can read it via **imread** function.

Comment: thank you very much for answer,Actually I solved the problem by convert the result from matrix to grayimage,So I could save it normally
                               oim2 =mat2gray(oim);